# Latest version of swiper not working , says "Can't resolve 'swiper'"

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

compiler says  Can't resolve 'swiper' even though I have installed the latest version of swiper and I am also importing the files just like what the offical website says. I am using react.

```js
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from 'swiper';

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/scrollbar';
```

Comment: Duplicate:Find the answers here if you still troubled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202975/module-not-found-cant-resolve-swiper-react