# Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/react'

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm also having the same problem with the latest version of Swiper. It worked on my previous project but not working right now. Not even that version. Tried on the latest version too.

Here is my code.

```
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      ...
    </Swiper>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Whenever I run my code it says, " Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/react' ".

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871

Comment: Agreed, seems to be an issue with `swiper` itself and not your code.

Comment: @DrewReese Let's see, man.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much the example code snippet right from their page, so... ‍♂️

Comment: @DrewReese I solved it, Default React Compiler doesn't support ESM packages. Now I'm using gatsby's latest starter template and that's working fine.

Comment: @ArikChakma Can you please state what is different in new gatsby template? Are you using Gatsby v4?

Answer (score 41):

swiper version 7 only works if you have pure ESM. if not you have to downgrade to version 6.8.4

npm:

```
npm install swiper@6.8.4
```

yarn:

```
yarn add swiper@6.8.4
```

then add the structure like below:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css'
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css'

<Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      centeredSlides
      onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
      onSwiper={swiper => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
```

version 6.8.4 documentation is [here](https://swiper6.vercel.app/swiper-api)

Comment: How do you import Pagination and Navigation?

Answer (score 32):

Create React App doesn't support pure ESM packages yet. It is still possible to use Swiper (7.2.0+) with it.

In this case we need to use direct file imports

```js
// Core modules imports are same as usual
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
// Direct React component imports
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js';

// Styles must use direct files imports
import 'swiper/swiper.scss'; // core Swiper
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.scss'; // Navigation module
import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.scss'; // Pagination module
```

source: Swiper docs | https://swiperjs.com/react#usage-with-create-react-app

Comment: Why on earth would that be pushed all the way to the bottom of the page without any reference from the top where it specifically tells you how to start using swiper?

Comment: If you do a clean install of create-react-app and add this it still doesn't work, 

gives a `Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.css' in` error

Comment: Thx, swiper.js 7.4.1 also works

Comment: @HardBurn We were able to get around this by patching the package.json file by appending `"./swiper.scss": "./swiper.scss"`, or whatever you need to the exports

Answer (score 13):

There is no index file in the swiper module.
so just change the import path from

```
 import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react`'; 

 to

 import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react';
```

---

Answer (score 6):

**Fix Swiperjs on React**
It seems issue with latest version of swiperjs.

> - uninstall swiperjs if you already added to your react project
>
>   `npm uninstall swiper`
> - install Swiperjs version 6.0.2
>
>   `npm install swiper@6.0.2`

Let me know if this helps :) Happy Hacking

Comment: Gatsby complier support new one but react doesn't. Btw thanks for your help, man.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react';
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
```

Source: [github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871](http://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871)

**UPDATED**

Now, if you upgrade **react-scripts** to **5.0.0**, you can use:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a problem with swiper version7~:

https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4871

use any previous swiper version c:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Gatsby complier solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, fixed with changing the import to:

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
```

and downgrade swiper to `swiper@6.0.2` version

Comment: Yeah that works but I solved it using gatsby. It supports swiper new version.

Answer (score 2):

Iam use swiper 6.8.4
you need to use direct file imports like :

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react/swiper-react";
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css";
import "swiper/swiper.min.css";
import 'swiper/modules/effect-fade/effect-fade';
import "swiper/modules/navigation/navigation";
import "swiper/modules/pagination/pagination";
```

Answer (score 2):

as **@vyvu** said if you now upgrade react-scripts to 5.0.0, you can use:

```
// I am using swiper version "^8.1.0"
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing path to swiper/react/swiper-react.js also worked for me

Answer (score 2):

**In 2023**, every above solution is deprecated.

I am using `Swiper v11.0.4` with `create-react-app`.

If everything is working fine for you and you are getting an `eslint` unresolved import error so below is the only solution for you. It will resolve `CSS` and `import` errors both.

```js
'import/no-unresolved': [
  'error',
  {
    ignore: ['^swiper/'],
  },
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what swiper team did in their [demos](https://swiperjs.com/demos) e.g. [react-manipulation-example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xtosg).
They are using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) for build and development.

- `package.json`

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
```

- `vite.config.ts`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()]
})
```

Here is [how to migration existing CRA to vite](https://www.darraghoriordan.com/2021/05/16/migrating-from-create-react-app-to-vite/)
**Note:** It might need to create a new fresh version of vite project.

Although the activities of some team members to address this issue appear to be exhausted, I believe migrating to the prior version is not the best action plan.
Referencing certain [gist](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c) for migrating to the pure ESM package, as well as some difficulties with create-react-app that are perplexing [#10933](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10933), [#10892](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10892), ..., might not have good development experience.

Answer (score 1):

please use this version. It's worked for me.

```
npm i swiper@^6.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
// Core modules imports are same as usual
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
// Direct React component imports
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js';

// Styles must use direct files imports
import 'swiper/swiper.scss'; // core Swiper
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.scss'; // Navigation module
import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.scss'; // Pagination module
```

OR
you can check link => https://swiperjs.com/react#usage-with-create-react-app

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32032775)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest SwiperJS version, for example ^8.4.6

npm:

```
npm install swiper
```

yarn:

```
yarn add swiper
```

Code sample:

```
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y, EffectCube } from 'swiper';
import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css';

export const Slider = ({ slides }) => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y, EffectCube]}
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      navigation
      pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
      effect={"cube"}
      cubeEffect={{
        shadow: true,
        slideShadows: true,
        shadowOffset: 20,
        shadowScale: 0.94,
      }}
    >
      {slides.map((slide) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={slide.image}>
          <img src={slide.image} alt={slide.title}/>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  )

}
```

Swiper React is available only via NPM as a part of the main Swiper library, but import is the nest:

```
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from "swiper/react";
```

Don't forget to use **SwiperSlide** component.

In case some additional plugins are required, import from 'swiper', for example

```
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y, EffectCube } from 'swiper';
```

Working code sample - [React Swiper](https://github.com/MaksymRudnyi/turorials/blob/swipper-js/client/src/slider.js)

Explanation reference - [How to use react-swiperjs](https://youtu.be/KL_yIf5uiJo)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is usually related to vulnerable dependencies in `npm`

It worked for me by running the following command:

```
npm audit fix --force
```

for last version (swiper 11)