# export 'Pagination' (imported as 'Pagination') was not found in 'swiper' (possible exports: Swiper, default)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, swiper.js, react-swiper

I wanted to add the Pagination from swiper.
The import statement I used is `import { Pagination } from "swiper";` 
My configuration:

[image]

The **error** i`m getting is :
[image]

I have seen at multiple places that its working fine but not sure why I`m encountering this issue.

Also on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69202975/module-not-found-cant-resolve-swiper-react) stackflow article it say the same import statement as of aforementioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create React App doesn't support pure ESM packages yet. It is still possible to use Swiper (7.2.0+) with it.

In this case we need to use direct file imports:

```
// Core modules imports are same as usual
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';
// Direct React component imports
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/swiper-react.mjs';

// Styles must use direct files imports
import 'swiper/swiper.scss'; // core Swiper
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.scss'; // Navigation module
import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.scss'; // Pagination module
```

**For reference :** https://swiperjs.com/react#usage-with-create-react-app

Seems like earlier pagination would work using `import { Pagination } from "swiper";`.
But now its `import { Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';`
Just by adding `/modules` in my import statement fixed the issue.

Comment: How good. I was banging my head for days. Just adding ``import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper/modules";`` instead of ``import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper";`` solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped you.